# Карта на JavaFX

Tags: javafx, карты, map

Доброй ночи. Приложение на JavaFX - desktop. Нужно сделать карту, для начала города. Как взять файл, например, от Navitel в *.mn7 и его отрисовывать? Или как еще можно сделать. Интернета нет на ПК.

Comment: Уточните вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать конкретный ответ. Карт есть много, выбор зависит от разных факторов, в том числе и вкусов разработчика. Если вам нужно отрисовать именно .mn7 из Navitel, напишите об этом.

Comment: Благодарю, написал новый вопрос

Comment: `Благодарю, написал новый вопрос` — не надо задавать новый вопрос, вас просят уточнить детали *этого* вопроса.